# Can I get into an "abandoned" user profile on windows 7 without the password?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

I'm using my wife's old PC since she got a MAC several years ago. She has lost an important file that may be in her old user profile on my (her old) computer, but she has no idea what her password was. Is there any way to get to that old user profile?

Comment: The profile files should all be accessible by navigating to the profile directory in `\Users`. You don't need to log in as that user, though you may need to run as administrator, depending on your security settings. But if the file was important it will have been backed up, so look there.

Comment: What also might work is to browse to the C drive enter the Users folder and enter into the folder named with your wife's username (depending on the setup performed could be another name) and click on Continue on the prompt You don't have currently permission to access this folder. Another option boot from a live linux flash drive and copy the documents needed (if you are comfortable using something like that)

Answer (score 2):

Open the start menu, type CMD and then right click on it to choose "run as administrator".

[image: cmd run as admin]

Let's assume your wife's profile name was Tiffany.

```
net user tiffany NewPass
```

The new password for her profile would be 'NewPass'

Syntax is

```
net user username password
```

where *password* is the desired new password. Press enter and you can now logout and login using her account.

[Here](http://ss64.com/nt/net_useradmin.html) are some additional usages of the net user command as well as the above command.

Comment: windows 7 doesn't have the Win-X command menu

Comment: @magicandre1981 good call, I missed that tag. it's been edited to reflect something closer to win7

Answer (score 0):

Once you get to an administrative command prompt (right-click on `cmd` in the Start menu and choose *Run as administrator*), you can use these commands to adjust the folder's access control lists to give you full control:

1. To move the current directory to the Users folder:

   ```
   cd \users
   ```
2. Assuming the folder name is `wife` and your username is `you`, grant recursive Full Control to your user account:

   ```
   icacls wife /grant:r you:(OI)(CI)F
   ```

The `:r` on `/grant` means "add a new explicit permission, rather than demolishing existing ones." `(OI)` means "object inherit" (i.e. apply to all files), `(CI)` means "container inherit" (apply to all folders), and `F` means "full control."

On a domain, you'd need to prefix the username with the domain's NetBIOS name and a backslash, to product something like `YOURDOMAIN\you`.

Once finished, close the command prompt. Your user account, even un-elevated, will then be able to freely access everything in that folder.